# Python: Lambda in a sum

Tags: python, lambda, sum, closures

I'm trying to do the following, which is a representative example of what my final goal will be:

```
 yu = lambda x: 0
 for i in range(0,5):
      yu = lambda x: i + yu(x)
```

Unfortunately, it returns:

`RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

when I do:

```
print yu(0)
```

The print statement should return 10.

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Why are you even using `lambda` here? You're trying to define a function and give it a name—so why not use `def`?

Comment: Final goal is to sum a bunch of functions, starting with an initialized sum function to 0. Coming from MATLAB, it just seemed the natural thing to do: to use lambda functions for this goal. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: In Python, there is nothing that a `lambda` can do that a `def` cannot, except to appear in the middle of an expression (and save the 7 characters of typing `return `). And there's a lot that a `def` can do that a `lambda` cannot, and they're easier to wrap your head around. Most importantly, `def` blocks are among the few things that create a new scope in Python (`class` blocks and modules are others; control statements like `for` and `if` are not, and there is no expression like a `let` that does so either).

Comment: More importantly, this probably isn't the way you want to solve this problem in the first place. What you're going to end up with is a stack of functions that you call through—which is fine in a language with tail recursion optimization, especially one that can inline through tail calls, but in Python it just means stack limits, hard-to-read tracebacks, and inefficiency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 yu = lambda x: i + yu(x)
```

This makes `yu` into a function that always calls itself, guaranteeing infinite recursion with no base case.

Why? Well, you've built a closure where `yu` (and `i`) are the local variables in the function or module that the `for` loop is part of. That's not what you want; you want to close over the *current values* of `yu` and `i`, not the outer variables.

I'm not sure why you're even using `lambda` in the first place. If you want to define a function and give it a name, use `def`.

Here's an easy solution:

```
def yu(x): return 0
def make_new_yu(yu, i):
    def new_yu(x): return i + yu(x)
    return new_yu
for i in range(0, 5):
    yu = make_new_yu(yu, i)
```

By making the wrapping explicit, the correct way to do it becomes the most obvious way to do it.

You can, of course, use a `lambda` inside `make_new_yu` without making things more confusing:

```
def make_new_yu(yu, i):
    return lambda x: i + yu(x)
```

And you can even make the initial definition a `lambda` if you want. But if you insist on not having *any* `def` statements, you need to force the right values into the closure in some way, e.g., by using the default-value trick. That's much easier to get wrong—and harder to read once you've done it.

If you want an intuitive understanding of the difference, without learning the details: a function body defines a new scope. So, defining the function (by `lambda` or `def`) inside that function means your closure is from that new scope.

Comment: Nope, this returns `20`.. you didn't bind `i` in the context of `make_new_yu`, and are instead using it as a global.

Comment: Ah, right, he's also closing over the wrong `i`, as well as using the wrong `yu`. Fixed.

Comment: @abarnert I like your approach since I'm a complete newbie in Python. It works in the interactive prompt. However, when I put the for loop inside a main function, I get an error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'yu' referenced before assignment. Why is that?

Comment: @Eli: If you're trying to rebind the global variable `yu` from inside a function, you have to write `global yu` before using it in the function. (If you're trying to create a new local variable `yu`, starting with a copy of the global `yu`… really, the easiest thing to do there is just not call your local variable `yu`.)

Answer (score 5):

In the end, you have:

```
yu = lambda x: i + yu(x)
```

but `yu` will be looked up at *runtime*, not when you constructed the lambda. Do this instead:

```
for i in range(0,5):
    yu = lambda x, yu=yu: i + yu(x)
```

This does *not* return `10`, though. It returns `20` instead:

```
>>> yu = lambda x: 0
>>> for i in range(0,5):
...     yu = lambda x, yu=yu: i + yu(x)
... 
>>> yu(0)
20
```

because now `i` is still looked up from the context (and by now the loop has finished so it's `4`). Solution? Move `i` to a keyword argument too:

```
for i in range(0,5):
    yu = lambda x, yu=yu, i=i: i + yu(x)
```

*Now* this works:

```
>>> yu = lambda x: 0
>>> for i in range(0,5):
...     yu = lambda x, yu=yu, i=i: i + yu(x)
... 
>>> yu(0)
10
```

Moral of the story? Bind your context properly to the scope of the lambda.

Comment: I think something like `x=i` is also required in the lambda : `yu = lambda x=i, yu=yu: x + yu(x)`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Eh, come again? `x` is the one positional parameter that you pass in and on. Setting a default value for it *makes no sense* since it'll never use that default.

Comment: Ah! yes you're right, `i=i` is what I should have used(to prevent the closure thing).

Comment: Really, someone who doesn't know how to understand closures in Python shouldn't be writing code like this. And even someone who _does_ will be better served by a explicit `def`.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the answers you try to sum up 0, 1, 2, 3, 4. If that was right you could use the following lambda expression:

```
yu = lambda x: x + yu(x+1) if x<4 else x
```

For `yu(0)` it delivers 10 as a result. The break condition is the value of `x` which is required to stay smaller than 4 in order to add up.

Assuming that is what you desired to do, you should leave out the loop for a rather concise statement.

This lambda expression differentiates from the others in resulting in different values (other than 10, when not choosing 0 as the parameter x) depending on the given argument.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I didn't fully understand your question, but could anyone check if this is what he meant?

*I assumed you wouldn't need an iterator to generate a list of digits*

```
yu = lambda x: x[0] + yu(x[1:]) if x!=[] else 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
facto = lambda f: f if f == 0 else f + facto(f-1)
print(facto(4))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.